# Expose static files from FastAPI app behind Traefik proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, fastapi, traefik, static-files

In my FastAPI app I've mounted the `static` directory to serve static files as follows:

```py
app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')
```

The FastAPI app runs from inside a Docker container defined as follows:

```yaml
fhback:
    container_name: fhback
    build:
      context: ./back
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8000
    command: "gunicorn --workers 6 --timeout 60 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app"
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.fhback.rule=Host(`example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)
      - traefik.http.routers.fhback.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.fhback.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.middlewares.firehouse-compress.compress=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.fhback-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/api
      - traefik.http.routers.fhback.middlewares=firehouse-compress,fhback-stripprefix
```

With these Traefik labels, I can access my Swagger with `https://example.com/api/docs` and also call API endpoints from the front end with `https://example.com/api/...` (externally) or `http://fhouse:8000/api/...` (locally, from Docker).

But I never can access my static files in the `static` dir! When I do `http://fhouse:8000/api/static/any-file.txt` from any Docker container within the Docker network, it works fine. But when I try `https://example.com/api/static/any-file.txt`, I get connection error. I realize I must do something with the Traefik config... Any ideas?

## Update

There is also another service running in the same Docker bundle defined as follows:

```yaml
fhfront:
    container_name: fhfront
    build:
      context: ./front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8090
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - ./front:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.fhfront.rule=Host(`example.com`,`www.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.fhfront.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.fhfront.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.middlewares.firehouse-compress.compress=true
      - traefik.http.routers.fhfront.middlewares=firehouse-compress
```

This service is the frontend (website) which seems to mask all requests to `example.com/static` or `example.com/api/static`. How can I explicitly exclude the `static` route from `example.com` in the `fhfront` container? So that it gets picked up by `fhback` and serve static files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
├── back
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── static
│       └── test.html
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Both Traefik and the API are set up as services.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:v2.5
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

  fhback:
    container_name: fhback
    build:
      context: ./back
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.fhback.rule=Host(`example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      - traefik.http.services.fhback.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
      - traefik.http.middlewares.firehouse-compress.compress=true
      - traefik.http.routers.fhback.middlewares=firehouse-compress,fhback-stripprefix
      - traefik.http.middlewares.testheader.headers.customresponseheaders.X-Test-Header=TraefikProxy
      - traefik.http.routers.fhback.middlewares=testheader
    depends_on:
      - traefik

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

`back/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

The static file is being baked straight into the image. You can use a volume mount to share static files from the host though.

`back/main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

`requirements.txt`

```
fastapi==0.109.2
uvicorn==0.27.1
```

To test:

```bash
curl -v --resolve example.com:80:127.0.0.1 http://example.com/static/test.html
```

I added a response header via the Traefik labels in `docker-compose.yml`. If you look at the output below you'll see that header, confirming that the response came via Traefik. You can also see it in the logs in the top panel of the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! The problem in my case seems to be that I have a different service, fhfront, also behind Traefik, which seem to mask the /static route bacause it resolves directly to example.com. Pls see updated question.

Comment: In that case why not serve the static files from the `fhfront` service?

Comment: I can update my answer to serve static from the front end service. However, before I do that, it would be good to have some clarity on whether this is a solution you'd consider. From my perspective static files are normally served from the front end, so this would be a natural place to do it.

Equally you could do it using the approach above.

Comment: Hmm, sounds sound! Yes, I think I could do that!

Comment: Let me know how that goes!